# How to estimate regex parameters (find more strict version)?

Tags: python, regex

```
pattern = '(0*10{1,5}1)'
m = re.search(pattern, '00010000010000')
print(m.group(0)) #result: 0001000001
```

`(0*)` means any number of 0, `(0{1,5})` means number of zeros between 1 and 5.

In the provided example the regexp matched the strng `0001000001`. It contains 3 zeros at the beginning `(0*)` and 5 zeros after the first occurrence of 1 `(0{1,5})`. Exact regexp would be `(0{3}10{5}1)`. How to find this more strict version (regex2) that gives the same result given data and regex1?

Comment: You may capture each quantified pattern, and then find the length of each captured substring and build the pattern accordingly.

Comment: is it exponential complexity? n parameters with m possible values, m^n

Comment: Just getting substring length is not that complex.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: (0*10{1,5}1) -> (0A10B1), A from 0 to inf, B from 0 to inf. Test all patterns and choose the simplest?

Comment: See my idea implemented below in Cedric's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the 0 groups with

```
pattern = '((0*)1(0{1,5})1)'
m = re.search(pattern, '00010000010000')
```

Then build your strict pattern with

```
strict_pattern = f'(0{{{len(m[2])}}}*10{{{len(m[3])}}}1)'

print(strict_pattern)  # result: (0{3}*10{5}1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex is *code* executed by an engine. With loops, backtracks, exceptions, ...

Apart form special ones, each char is an instruction : "Match".

Hence, the most efficient regex that matches `00010000010000` is : `00010000010000`

The pseudo-code equivalents are :

```
/* 00010000010000 */
read(0);
read(0);
read(0);
read(1);
read(0);
read(0);
read(0);
read(0);
read(0);
read(1);
read(0);
read(0);
read(0);
read(0);

/* 0{3}10{5}1 */
i=0
{read(0); i = i+1; if(i!=3) repeat;}
read(1);
i=0
{read(0); i = i+1; if(i!=5) repeat;}
read(1);
```

I agree the second block is shorter. But it's also longer to execute, and in case of failure more steps to backtrack